# From ODBC - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, syntax-error

I am connecting to our data warehouse via an ODBC connector through Power BI and I have the following statement

SELECT * FROM T_OL_DETL WHERE FY_CD = '2020'
LIMIT 10000;

I am getting an error that says "SQL command not properly ended". Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.
Alex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL command not properly ended when using LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928825/sql-command-not-properly-ended-when-using-limit)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't support `LIMIT`.  Instead, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_OL_DETL
WHERE FY_CD = '2020' 
FETCH FIRST 10000 ROW ONLY;
```

Normally, you would only use this with `ORDER BY`.