# Can't update only 1 row. How to change 1 row?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-limit

I found out that *Oracle* does not support `LIMIT` clause unlike to *MySQL* and to update only 1 row in table i've tried this:

```sql
UPDATE "Schedule" 
   SET "Position" = 'Manager' 
 WHERE "Position" IN 
       (SELECT "Position" 
          FROM "Schedule" 
         WHERE "Position"='Tester' 
         OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

And 3 rows are updated.

When i run this:

```sql
SELECT "Position" 
  FROM "Schedule" 
 WHERE "Position"='Tester' 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

i get only one row (as it should be).

But updating 1 row doesn't work as i mentioned before. Are there any other methods to update only 1 specific row?

Comment: Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928825/sql-command-not-properly-ended-when-using-limit

Comment: You've tagged *MySql* which *does* support `limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just a slight, provided that your DB's version is at least `12c`, change by replacing the part `WHERE Position IN (SELECT Position` with `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID` as having a primary column. The current case has no sense, since all testers will be converted to managers even replacing the `IN <subquery>` with `='Tester'`. So use the following update statement by removing double quotes

```sql
UPDATE Schedule
   SET Position = 'Manager'
 WHERE ID IN
       (SELECT ID
          FROM Schedule
         WHERE Position = 'Tester'
         FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a3f0265b65ea7fe8556eba07234c4d3c)</kbd>

Comment: i get this error.. ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

Comment: What's your DB's version? @a_needs_help

Comment: version is this ((  19c

Comment: did you remove the double-quotes @a_needs_help ? Btw, do you have a primary key column ?

Comment: thanks a lot, i found where the problem was :)

Comment: Can you help, please, with taking 3 last rows of table? i've tried TOP(3) or using variable of num of rows but it didn't work out

Comment: @a_needs_help  you can pick the last three one while sorting descendingly such as `ORDER BY ID DESC FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: my task was to order ascendingly by salary and take 3 rows with largest salaries

Comment: @a_needs_help Can you share your sample data and table structure within a demo as stated within the answer ?

Comment: WITH SRC AS (
    SELECT TOP (3) Num FROM Schedule
    ORDER BY Salary ASC
)
SELECT * FROM SRC

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `"Schedule"` table would have a primary key and you'd use that to perform your update. Assuming that `"Schedule"` doesn't have a primary key you can use ROWID:

```
UPDATE "Schedule" 
  SET "Position" = 'Manager' 
  WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID
                    FROM "Schedule" 
                    WHERE "Position" = 'Tester' 
                    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

Note that using ROWID like this is very poor practice, and all tables should have a primary key specified when they're created so that individual rows can be found reliably. For a column or set of columns to be a valid primary key they must be A) non-NULL, B) unique, and C) unchanging.

Also - I strongly suggest that you get in the habit of using names for tables and columns which do not require that they be quoted. Quoted identifiers are an opportunity for syntax errors that do nothing to make your life better. If you create a table named `SCHEDULE` you can still refer to is as `Schedule`, `ScHeDuLe`, `schedule`, or whatever other combination of upper and lower case letters you care to use in your code.