# How can i avoid rownum as a column when limiting records in oracle?

Tags: oracle, limit, rownum

when i run the query:

```
select * 
  from ( select a.*, 
                ROWNUM rnum 
           from ( select * 
                    from test 
                   order by null ) a  
          where ROWNUM <= 2000 )
  where rnum  >=1
```

I'm getting all the columns along with rownum as a separate column which I don't want, How to achieve this or is there any way to limit records?

Comment: By specifying the list of columns explicitly - always a good idea.

Comment: is there any other way for limiting records ? @NicholasKrasnov

Comment: there are good answers to this question, but if you don't want rownum as a column in the result, then don't include it as a column in your select.  Easy as that.

Comment: i have already tried it, Can you edit the query like you said @unleashed

Comment: @svsLm  It is already answered for you below in the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the final filter is for `ROWNUM >= 1` (which will always be true), you can eliminate that and just use:

```
select * 
from   (
  select * 
  from   test 
  order by null
)  
where ROWNUM <= 2000
```

*(Note: `ORDER BY NULL` will apply a non-deterministic ordering.)*

If you want to specify a different starting row then you will need to specify the columns you want to return:

```
select col_1,
       col_2,
       -- ...
       col_n
from   (
  select a.*,
         ROWNUM rnum
  from   (
    select * 
    from   test 
    order by null
  ) a
  where ROWNUM <= 2000
)
WHERE rnum > 1000
```

In Oracle 12c you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
ORDER BY NULL
FETCH FIRST 2000 ROWS ONLY;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
ORDER BY NULL
OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Got it, I just want to know other than using rownum is there any option for limiting records? @MT0

Comment: @svsLm Depends on your version - I have just updated for Oracle 12c. You could also use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/1509264) for other options/examples.