# How to correct pagination in oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, pagination

I am showing user record of how many forms he/she has accepted and for that purpose I am using pagination in php. Data is fetched from oracle database and shown in the table. I am using pagination, but when I go on next page it shows the previous record's new records are not shown.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $user_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"select * from userM where user_name = '$user_name'");
    $result = oci_execute($sql);

    while(($row = oci_fetch_array($sql,OCI_BOTH)) != false ){
        $approvedBy = $row[1];
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $_GET['page'] = 0;
    }else{
        // Convert the page number to an integer
        $_GET['page'] = (int)$_GET['page'];
    }
    $varPage = $_GET['page'];
    if($varPage == "" || $varPage == "1"){
        $page1 = 0;
    }else{
        $page1 = ($varPage*6)-6;
    }
    $approvedBy = strtoupper($approvedBy);

    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM formC where UPPER(approvedBy) = '$approvedBy' AND rownum < 7");
    oci_execute($sql);

    while(($row = oci_fetch_array($sql,OCI_BOTH)) != false )  {
        $accountingNo = $row[0];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo  $row[0] ?></td>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo  $row[1] ?></td>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo  $row[2]  ?></td>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo $row[3]?></td>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo $row[4] ?></td>
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo $row[7] ?></td>         
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
$sql1 = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM formC where UPPER(approvedBy) = '$approvedBy'");
oci_execute($sql1);
$count = oci_fetch_all($sql1,$abc);
$a=$count/6;
$a = ceil($a);

for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++){
    ?>
    <a href="approvedList.php?page=<?php echo $b?>" style="text-decoration;align:center: none;" class="btn btn-success "><?php echo $b." "; ?></a>
    <?php
}
oci_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), page 181:

> The canonical paging query for Oracle8i onwards is given on http://asktom.oracle.com:
>
> ```
> select *
>   from ( select a.*, rownum as rnum
>          from (YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by) a
>          where rownum <= MAX_ROW )
>   where rnum >= MIN_ROW
> ```
>
> Here, MIN_ROW is the row number of
>   first row and MAX_ROW is the row number of the last row to return.

There is even a full example script:

> ```
> <?php
> $c = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
> $mystmt = "select city from locations order by city";
> $minrow = 4; // row number of first row to return
> $maxrow = 8; // row number of last row to return
> $pagesql = "select *
>             from ( select a.*, rownum as rnum
>                    from ( $mystmt ) a
>                    where rownum <= :maxrow)
>             where rnum >= :minrow";
> $s = oci_parse($c, $pagesql);
> oci_bind_by_name($s, ":maxrow", $maxrow);
> oci_bind_by_name($s, ":minrow", $minrow);
> oci_execute($s);
> oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
> var_dump($res);
> ?>
> ```

---

***Edit:***

As [mentioned by Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687355/how-to-correct-pagination-in-oracle/45688396?noredirect=1#comment78410115_45688396), in Oracle >=12.1 there is a cleaner way to do this using the [offset clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABHFGAA):

```
select *
from mytable
order by myfield
offset X rows fetch next Y rows only
```

Comment: Thank u for the help

Comment: With Oracle DB 12, you can now use OFFSET / FETCH NEXT, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABEAACC  This makes the SQL nicer and doesn't return the extra rownum column

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks, that's very useful! When can we expect the updated manual? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not oracle guy but I'm not suggest you select all rows and count them,I think it's better to use this code to count rows:

```
$sql1 = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM formC where UPPER(approvedBy) = '$approvedBy'");
    oci_execute($sql1);
$count = oci_fetch_all($sql1,$abc);
$a=$count/6;
```

[oracle count documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/count.php)

to resolve your problem see this question:[How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

you calculate current page and saved it in `$page1` but did not use it in your query!!

Comment: @NidaAkram I didn't test it, find correct query from documentation

Comment: i have read the documentation and done according to that problem is its showing error undefined index rows