# Order By and Limit gives error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the query below:

```
Select ID From Players order by ID limit 3;
```

It gives the error

> Command Not Properly Ended.

Also the queries below:

```
SQL> Select ID From Players order by ID limit 3;
     Select ID From Players order by ID limit 3
                               *
```

Gives similar error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where in [the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle don't have or support limit clause and thus you are getting error.

Use this query:

```
Select ID From Players order by ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

OR

```
Select ID From Players order by ID
where rownum between 1 and 3 order by ID desc;
```

> Cause: The SQL statement ends with an inappropriate clause.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support `limit`.  Oracle 12c supports `fetch first <n> rows only`.  In earlier versions you can use a subquery and `rownum`:

```
select *
from (select ID 
      from Players
      order by ID desc
     ) p
where rownum <= 3;
```