# 'limit' clause in Oracle SQL "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle, limit

I know that questions related to 'limit' have been asked before here,
and I have already referred to them. My question is somewhat different.

Here's my query:

```
select id,somecol from sometable where someval=2 order by id desc limit 3
```

I'm getting an error saying 'SQL command not properly ended'.
How do I resolve this? If you need additional information, feel free to tell me so.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering). Is this Oracle 12c? If so, replace "limit 3" with "FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY". If not, I think the standard Oracle-y thing to do is "SELECT * FROM (select id,somecol from sometable where someval=2 order by id desc) WHERE rownum <= 3"

Comment: what is your oracle version

Comment: My version is 11g. Express edition

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generally, we use LIMIT in MYSQL database and Rownum in Oracle.

**MySQL Syntax**:

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
LIMIT number;

**Oracle Syntax**:

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number;

**References:**

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: 'select id,somecol from sometable where someval=2 order by id desc where rownum<=3' should work, right?

Comment: okay, this worked! thank you!

Answer (score 13):

If you are running Oracle 12c, you could use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`:

```
SELECT id, somecol
       FROM sometable
      WHERE someval = 2
   ORDER BY id DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```