# Query limit in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create query with kind of limit.

`SELECT * FROM ALARMS WHERE OBJECT_ID=0 AND TIMESTAMP<=1525677504171 AND ROWNUM<=51 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC`

I use rownum but first it makes a limit and then it select ordered by. However I need to order first and then limit. I found here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that I should use `FETCH FIRST 51 ROWS ONLY`. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM ALARMS WHERE OBJECT_ID=0 AND TIMESTAMP<=1525677504171 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC FETCH FIRST 51 ROWS ONLY;
```

It throws me following error:

```
SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: You don't use `FETCH FIRST 51 ROWS ONLY` in your statement, but `FETCH FIRST 51 ROWS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FETCH FIRST` is only available since Oracle 12c.

For the `rownum` approach, use a subquery that contains `order by`, then limit the rows in the enclosing query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ALARMS WHERE OBJECT_ID=0 AND TIMESTAMP<=152567750417
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
) dt
WHERE ROWNUM<=51
```

Comment: It works but what doest `dt` mean?

Comment: That's alias for the derived table. I'm not sure it's necessary in Oracle, as I'm using multiple databases; in some of them it is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

You miss ONLY at the end. This syntax is available since 12c R1 if I remember correctly. Which Oracle version you use?

```
SELECT * FROM ALARMS WHERE OBJECT_ID=0 AND TIMESTAMP<=1525677504171 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC FETCH FIRST 51 ROWS ONLY
```

;

Edit:

Since your version is 11g then try to use such syntax (I hope it will work;))

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT a.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) rcnt 
    FROM ALARMS A WHERE OBJECT_ID=0 AND TIMESTAMP<=1525677504171) src  
WHERE src.rcnt <= 51
ORDER BY src.TIMESTAMP desc;
```

Comment: Relevant doc to support this: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g