# Is there another operator - other than rownum - in Oracle to display the top result in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I'm new to coding,please keep that in mind,currently I'm learning in Italian, therefore are some mistake in spelling.

I have a small Database regarding a dvd-rental, I write this code and the result is nicely showing, but I need only the top row.

```
select count(dvd_neloggio.id_dvd),
       film.titolo,
       grouping(dvd_neloggio.id_dvd) top
from dvd_neloggio
  inner join dvd on dvd_neloggio.id_dvd=dvd.id_dvd
  inner join film on dvd.id_film=film.id_film
group by dvd_neloggio.id_dvd,film.titolo
order by  dvd_neloggio.id_dvd;
```

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: `fetch first x rows only`?

Comment: ty you very much, i will try

Comment: @RobertKock `oracle` is tagged

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Please explain why you are using the `GROUPING()` function.  It doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: Thank you all very much, it worked with rownum. I am using Sqldeveloper

Comment: I'm only three months into the coding, so i had looking for other operators. I used grouping() just to see what happens.I finded grouping() more friendlier than group_id

Comment: I will try to explain as good as I can, I dont like rownum beucause you must insert after the query is done

Comment: `rownum` isn't an operator.

Comment: I found the right answer. I made a subquery with the Having statement, using the Max function! Thanks everybody for the assist!