# SELECT 50 MAX FIRST PRICES without a "WHERE" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, top-n

how to select the first maximum prices in a table without using the clause "where" ?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 50 * FROM tab ORDER BY Prices DESC` - depending on RDBMS `TOP/LIMIT/OFFSET - FETCH`

Comment: thank you  but u are using sql server in this case , i want it in mysql

Comment: I provided an answer already. Please read carefully.

Comment: thank you , sorry i've just seen it ^^

Comment: here is the result in sql oracl too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

If you want 50 rows, even when there are duplicates, then you can use:

```
select price
from t
order by price desc
limit 50;
```

If you want 50 distinct prices, then you can use:

```
select distinct price
from t
order by price desc
limit 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

In mysql -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY price desc LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work in mysql:

```
SELECT 
    select_list
FROM
    table_name
order by column_name
LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT price
FROM table
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 50;
```