# How can we display the last 7 Records from table in Oracle 11G SQL only?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I write this query without TOP and Limit only use the SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Please do a bit of searching before posting a question.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just sort the data one way, grab the records you want, then sort it the other way:

```
SELECT SOME_FIELD
  FROM (SELECT st.*
          FROM SOME_TABLE st
          ORDER BY SOME_FIELD DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 7
  ORDER BY SOME_FIELD ASC
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=922c1797a8f0bfb05eb291c684e493b7)