# Will the next call to ResultSet.next() fetch more rows from the database?

Tags: java, resultset

How can I find out if the next call to `ResultSet.next()` will fetch more rows from the database?

I could set the fetch size (e.g. `ResultSet.setFetchSize(1000)`) and then check if `ResultSet.getRow()` is a multiple of the fetch size (e.g. 1000).

This is cumbersome if the code is trying to auto-tune the fetch size to maximize row processing speed.  In other words, the fetch size may not be constant.

Note: I am using an Oracle database.  However, a solution for any database would be nice but not required.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  If you are iterating over a loop using `ResultSet#next`, then what is the problem with just letting the loop stop when no more records are available?

Comment: Let's say I am fetching a billion rows.  I can greatly improve the throughput if I set the fetch size to an optimal number.  I do not want to hand tune the fetch size for every query.  I would like the code to automatically tune the fetch size.

Comment: Then I suggest limiting the size of the result set in the query itself, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering).

Comment: Limiting the size of the result set is not going to help auto-tune the fetch size.  Besides, I want to process all the rows in the table (i.e. billions of rows).