# Openfire ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c, openfire

I have the following problem retrieving messages from the OpenFire Monitoring Service plugin. I discovered that the error is due to an incorrect query in the database but I still cannot detect the error for which the query is not working correctly.

```
SELECT
fromjid,
fromjidresource,
tojid,
tojidresource,
sentdate,
body,
stanza,
messageid,
barejid
FROM
(
SELECT
  DISTINCT ofmessagearchive.fromjid,
  ofmessagearchive.fromjidresource,
  ofmessagearchive.tojid,
  ofmessagearchive.tojidresource,
  ofmessagearchive.sentdate,
  ofmessagearchive.body,
  ofmessagearchive.stanza,
  ofmessagearchive.messageid,
  ofconparticipant.barejid
FROM
  ofmessagearchive
  INNER JOIN ofconparticipant ON ofmessagearchive.conversationid = 
ofconparticipant.conversationid
WHERE
  (
    ofmessagearchive.stanza IS NOT NULL
    OR ofmessagearchive.body IS NOT NULL
  )
  AND ofmessagearchive.messageid IS NOT NULL
  AND ofmessagearchive.sentdate >= 0
  AND ofmessagearchive.sentdate <= 1602748770287
  AND ofconparticipant.barejid = 'usuario3@192.168.0.79'
  AND (
    ofmessagearchive.tojid = 'usuario4@192.168.0.79'
    OR ofmessagearchive.fromjid = 'usuario3@192.168.0.79'
  )
ORDER BY
  ofmessagearchive.sentdate DESC
LIMIT
  100
 ) AS part
ORDER BY
sentdate
```

I get an error when doing the following query

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>
> Command line error:32 Column: 9

Comment: How many ( do you have, and how many )? Same number?

Comment: Does Oracle have LIMIT?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no `LIMIT` keyword available in Oracle and if you are using Oracle 12c you can use `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` instead of it.
2. You cannot use `AS` to give alias to the sub query and it is not recognised by Oracle. So either you can remove the alias  completely as you are not using it anywhere or just remove the `AS` and keep the `alias` name `part` only which should be fine.

Here is a good [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering/26051830#26051830) about the Oracle limiting result set and you can always look into other sites available such as [Oracle base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries) or the official document as well. For [11g solution](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-top-n-and-pagination-queries) you have to use `row_number`