# SQL Why does LIMIT 1 display more than one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm trying to display the titles where the number of actresses are 91, and from what I understood, `LIMIT 1` should limit the number of ROWS to 1. But here, I'm actually getting 2 titles back that both have 91 actresses playing in it. Why does LIMIT 1 not limit the number of rows to 1 here?

Thanks in advance!

````
SELECT title, COUNT(*) c
FROM title_100k AS T
JOIN cast_info_100k AS CI ON CI.movie_id = T.id
JOIN role_type AS R ON R.id = CI.role_id
WHERE R.id = 2
GROUP BY(t.id))
SELECT title FROM tempTable WHERE c IN
(SELECT c from tempTable 
EXCEPT SELECT c from tempTable WHERE c IN (SELECT c from tempTable WHERE c > 91) ORDER By c desc LIMIT 1);```
````

Comment: Your `LIMIT` is inside a subquery you're using for a semi-join. The limit is not applied to the outer query, so the outer query is free to return any number of rows that match the subquery.

Comment: Also the query you posted is incomplete. I guess `tempTable` is a CTE, but you've chopped off the first line that starts the CTE.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `LIMIT` is a product specific functionality.

Comment: @jarlh postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might because your LIMIT 1 is inside

```
(SELECT c
       from tempTable EXCEPT SELECT c
       from tempTable
       WHERE c IN (SELECT c from tempTable WHERE c > 91)
       ORDER By c desc
       LIMIT 1)
```

instead of outside

```
(SELECT c
       from tempTable EXCEPT SELECT c
       from tempTable
       WHERE c IN (SELECT c from tempTable WHERE c > 91)
       ORDER By c desc
       ) LIMIT 1
```

But you should check this answer [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering/26051830#26051830) because with newer version of Oracle, there are new options to limit the number of results.

Comment: LIMIT doesn't work with Oracle to begin with.