# Need to return just one record from a LEFT JOIN statement based on a criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have posted the relevant part of my code below, up to and including the left join statement that I need a hand with. This statement to bring in a time column is returning multiple records in some cases. This is expected as there are several unique times per e.pb_trans_id. However I only want to bring back the record with the latest time. Is there a way I can single it out this way?

'''

```
SELECT

    distinct a.transaction_id,
    b.currency_id,
    h.SIG_CURRENCY_CODE,
    b.charge_id,
    c.charge_type_id,
    d.charge_group,
    e.account_name,
    f.sig_entity_label,
    e.trading_userid,
    e.exchange_id,
    e.tradeable_instr_name,
    g.underlying_sym_bloomberg,
    g.fut_expiration_date,
    e.trade_date,
    a.rate * a.basis_value AS dma_fee,
    SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER () as DMA_FEE_TOTAL
FROM
    repldoadm.ire_estimate_trans_map       a
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_estimate         b ON a.estimate_id = b.estimate_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_lu               c ON b.charge_id = c.charge_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charge_types_lu          d ON c.charge_type_id = d.charge_type_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions    e ON a.transaction_id = e.pb_trans_id 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS timeformated,
            trans_id,
            pb_trans_id
        FROM
            repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions
    )                                      timestamp_table ON ( a.transaction_id = timestamp_table.trans_id or a.transaction_id = timestamp_table.pb_trans_id)
```

'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to the fact that there are two different ids in `vw_ire_trade_transactions`, but generically, here's a way to do it if there were only one id. Can't give a full answer without learning more about the `vw_ire_trade_transactions` dataset.

```
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS timeformated,
            pb_trans_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pb_trans_id ORDER BY create_ts DESC) AS rn
        FROM
            repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions
    ) timestamp_table 
    ON a.transaction_id = timestamp_table.pb_trans_id
    WHERE timestamp_table.rn=1
```