# Looking for string using CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, oracle

I am required to use char index to locate a section of a word and to be the first 100 object it finds inside a database but for some reason, it is giving me several errors and have no clue what is wrong. I am trying to avoid using LIKE function.

'''
SELECT CHARINDEX('Harry', TITLE ), TITLE
FROM Book
LIMIT 100;

'''
It keeps saying it is an invalid identifier. I have looked at several sources but can't seem to figure out what is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle uses INSTR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` is not a valid Oracle function and `LIMIT` is not used in Oracle. You want the `INSTR` function.

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT INSTR(title, 'Harry'),
       TITLE
FROM   Book
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

or, in earlier versions (since you aren't using an `ORDER BY` clause and are just getting the first 100 random rows):

```sql
SELECT INSTR(title, 'Harry'),
       TITLE
FROM   Book
WHERE  ROWNUM < 100;
```

---

If you want to use it as a filter and use an `ORDER BY` clause then:

```sql
SELECT TITLE
FROM   Book
WHERE  INSTR(title, 'Harry') > 0
ORDER BY title
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

or

```sql
SELECT title
FROM   (
  SELECT title
  FROM   Book
  WHERE  INSTR(title, 'Harry') > 0
  ORDER BY title
)
WHERE  ROWNUM < 100;
```

Comment: Not sure why but when using INSTR, my putout is different compared to when using Like function.
'''
SELECT TITLE
FROM Book
WHERE Title LIKE '%Harry%'
AND ROWNUM <= 100
ORDER BY TITLE;

SELECT INSTR(TITLE, '%Harry%'), TITLE
FROM Book
WHERE ROWNUM <= 100
ORDER BY TITLE;
'''
The output for the INSTR givers me the same values even i fi change the column.

Comment: @CalvinLee Don't use `ROWNUM` with `ORDER BY` in that way. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) for how to use it. And you don't need to use `%` with `INSTR`; just use `INSTR(title, 'Harry')`.

Comment: So I tried following the format of the link you sent , but the INSTR still doesn't pick up the values and give me everything in the column.

'''
SELECT INSTR(DESCRIPTION, 'Harry'), TITLE
FROM Book
ORDER BY TITLE
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
'''

Does the INSTR function not sort out the values that exist in the description?

Comment: @CalvinLee Only when you use it in a `WHERE` condition (as I show in the answer) and filter the rows.