# SQL Query returning all results with right data but can't figure out how to just show the most assignments completed

Tags: sql, oracle

Show the student first and last name, subject code and course number of the student who completed the most assignments where they scored over 85 points on each assignment. Show the number of assignments. Arrange the list by subject code, course number,  last name then first name.

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | SUBJ | COURS | NUMASSIGNMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deena | Filpo | CS | 4800 | 18 |
| Ellsworth | Dimucci | WEB | 2630 | 18 |

2 rows selected.

```
SELECT 
    s.FIRSTNAME,
    s.LASTNAME,
    c.SUBJECTCODE,
    c.COURSENUMBER,
    (COUNT(ascore.ASSIGNMENTTYPEID)) AS NUMASSIGNMENTS
FROM 
    STUDENTS s
JOIN 
    REGISTRATION r ON s.STUDENTID = r.STUDENTID
JOIN 
    SECTIONS sec ON r.SECTIONID = sec.SECTIONID
JOIN 
    COURSES c ON sec.COURSEID = c.COURSEID
JOIN 
    ASSIGNMENTSCORE ascore ON r.STUDENTID = ascore.STUDENTID AND 
    r.SECTIONID = ascore.SECTIONID
WHERE 
    ascore.SCORE > 85
GROUP BY 
    s.STUDENTID,
    s.FIRSTNAME,
    s.LASTNAME,
    c.SUBJECTCODE,
    c.COURSENUMBER
ORDER BY 
    c.SUBJECTCODE,
    c.COURSENUMBER,
    s.LASTNAME,
    s.FIRSTNAME;
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can use with your existing query is `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` or `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` as follows:

```
...
Your query without ORDER BY 
...
ORDER BY NUMASSIGNMENTS DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

You can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`, if there are multiple students with same `NUMASSIGNMENTS` completed for `SCORE > 85` and you want all of them into your query result.