# Difference when using ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I search for Oracle paging query on the net, and most of them told me to wrap the query twice:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT t.*, ROWNUM rn 
          FROM tableName t 
         WHERE ROWNUM < 200) 
 WHERE rn > 100
```

Just wondering if I can type it as:

```
SELECT *, ROWNUM rn 
  FROM tableName t 
 WHERE ROWNUN BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

It seems the second one works as well.  Is there any (performance) differences between these two query?

Comment: I think you have probably got the answer you need, but I find that people new to Oracle often struggle with paging queries, especially since mysql makes it so easy with the LIMIT key word. I'd say this is one of the most common things Oracle beginners do wrong, so I wrote an article about it recently - http://betteratoracle.com/posts/18-limiting-query-results-top-n-and-window-queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are filtering in the same query that the ROWNUM is being generated.  Hence the reason you must have a subquery generate the rownum first and then apply the filtering.  Why the BETWEEN works fine is probably some nuance of how the engine processes the query, but I would be wary that it might not consistently give you correct results.  So it's not a matter of performance as it is a matter of actually getting correct results.

This article explains why you have to put the greater than outside the subquery:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm

```
SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
```

"The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned."

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to use ROWNUM is:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM (SELECT t.*, 
               ROWNUM rn 
          FROM tableName t) AS x
 WHERE x.rn > 100
   AND x.rn < 200
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, so the two queries are not identical logic.

For more information on ROWNUM, see [this link (includes link to Oracle documentation](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/10/rownum-and-rowid.html).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. My major concern is there any performance differences between those two queries in my questions. Can you have a look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle
It wrap the query twice.

Comment: @GaryX: As I said, the queries provided aren't identical; the second query will return everything in the table.  Performance is a concern until you get valid data.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, did you mean to say, "Performance is _not_ a concern until you get valid data"?