# Paging results from a table having a varchar as PK

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, paging

How can I page results from a table with this schema?

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE"
(
   "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
   "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
   "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
   CONSTRAINT "MY_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NAME")
)
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle . Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: What query do you want to add paging to?

Comment: @a1ex07 Perhaps, but it's not clear to me how rownum works.

Comment: @AdamWenger It's a simple "select *" to map rows to domain objects so they can be displayed in a GUI.

Comment: @AdamWenger: Take a look :http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm . Briefly, `rownum` returns a number in which a row appears in result. So, to get first 10 rows you just append `WHERE rownum <11`. Keep in mind that you cannot do `WHERE rownum>10` to get all but first 10 results (rownum > postive number is always false), so you need to use derived tables.

Comment: Thanks @a1ex07 I took a look at the links in your comments.  I'm not very familiar with Oracle, but I'll surely reference these as I move forward.

Comment: @AdamWenger If you're up for some experimenting, it's possible to download an express version of Oracle. There is also a great front-end called Sql Developer which saves having to go through the console or web interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  Currently, I can only be so confident with some of my answers for other SQL versions here when I am testing against `SQL Server 2012 CTP3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing my answer off the suggestion in the question comments, this should work for your table.

```
SELECT r.Name, r.Status. r.Description
FROM
(
    SELECT t.Name, t.Status. t.Description, rownum RowNumber
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Name, Status, Description
        FROM YourTable
        ORDER BY Name ASC
    ) AS t
    WHERE rownum < (pageNumber * pageSize) + 1
) AS r
WHERE RowNumber >= ((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize) + 1
```

A good explanation of what rownum does can be found on [AskTom.Oracle.com](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:948366252775)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what rownum does exactly? Running `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE rownum = 1` gives a result but any numbers higher than 1 turn up empty. So it's apparently not an index.

Comment: I've added a link to a good explanation to your question in my answer.  It does a better job explaining it than I could here.

Comment: Thanks. It works great and works flawlessly on the application side :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something in your select-statement,

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY NAME LIMIT ($curpage * 10), 10
```

$curpage being the current page, and the 10 multiplied by that being how many records you want to show per page.

Comment: Good suggestion. Oracle 11g doesn't seem to accept LIMITs though: `00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`. In fact, Oracle seems to be missing a few things that are taken for granted on other databases :)