# Retrieve increments of rows from multiple rows

Tags: oracle, rows, subset

I am trying to find a way to retrieve a subset of rows from multiple rows returned; and increment through the subset.

So as an example:

Table A as 1000 records. I do a select * to retrieve all records, but I only want the first 100. Then, I want subsequent queries to return the next 100, and so on, until I reach the end (1000'th row).

If anyone knows how to do this please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `I do a select * to retrieve all records` is wrong interpretation of `*`. `select * ..` means selecting all columns from table, and not all rows.

Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/241643/1551233) for pagination. As also posted by @jonearles.

Comment: Thanks champ - *high-five*