# How to add offset in a "select" query in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pagination, rownum

How to add an offset in a "select" query in Oracle 11g.
I only know how to add the limit by e.g `rownum <= 5`
this question is not a duplicate, I already checked the other questions and are not related to mine.

So, how to add the offset in Oracle 11g ?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Comment: The question should be reworded as your meaning of offset may or may not be related to the OFFSET clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paging with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it easily on `12c` by specifying `OFFSET`.

In `12c`,

```
SELECT val
FROM   table
ORDER BY val
OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

To do the same on `11g` and prior, you need to use `ROWNUM` twice, `inner query` and `outer query` respectively.

The same query in `11g`,

```
SELECT val
FROM   (SELECT val, rownum AS rnum
        FROM   (SELECT val
                FROM   table
                ORDER BY val)
        WHERE rownum <= 8)
WHERE  rnum > 4;
```

Here `OFFSET` is 4.

Comment: @psaraj12, if you mean to get rows in descending order, then just use `DESC` in `inner query`.

Comment: how to do this with LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @Toolkit Doesn't matter. You could have your result set as inner query and apply the TOP N query.

Comment: @LalitKumarB thanks, I am now trying to do this with a materialized view that is a JOIN query.  Any idea how to do pagination based on parent table? thanks

Comment: @Toolkit Apply on the result set. Or use a WITH clause to make it look simpler

Answer (score 3):

You can use ROW_NUMBER function for that.

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT *
  FROM(SELECT t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) rn -- whatever ordering you want
         FROM your_table t
      )
 WHERE rn >= ... -- your offset
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

for oracle 11g, suppose you have a table user, for limit and offset you can do:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT USER.*,
                row_number() over (partition by 1 order by 1) as rnum
         from USER
     )
where rnum <= 100 --limit
  and rnum > 0 --offset
```

let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the function LAG or LEAD in oracle

```
The LAG function is used to access data from a previous row

The LEAD function is used to return data from the next row
```

Usage:-

```
LAG  (value_expression [,offset] [,default]) OVER ([query_partition_clause] order_by_clause)
LEAD (value_expression [,offset] [,default]) OVER ([query_partition_clause] order_by_clause)
```

Please find the [this link](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) for examples

Comment: All you need is `ROWNUM`

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B. what you wrote makes sense as long as limiting rows in the ouptut is concerned. I would say that the question is not fully clear and should be reworded (offset may be understood differently).

Answer (score 0):

For pagination in Oracle 11g , We can use `ROWNUM`.

This is the example.

```
WITH STUDENT_PAGINATION AS (
    SELECT
        STUDENT.*,
        ROWNUM AS RN
    FROM
        STUDENT
    ORDER BY
        ID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    STUDENT_PAGINATION
WHERE
    RN >=5
    AND RN <=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Oracle 11g

Based on [@Ibrahima Timera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8631958/ibrahima-timera)'s  answer, but with a **behavior like Postgres's LIMIT and OFFSET**, with:

- **LIMIT = max number of rows fetched**
- **OFFSET = skipped rows before first fetched element**

In the example below on a USER table, 10 is the LIMIT, 50 is the OFFSET :

```
SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT USER.*,
                row_number() over (partition by 1 order by 1) as rnum
         from USER
     )
where rnum <= (10 + 50) -- LIMIT + OFFSET
and rnum > 50 -- OFFSET
```