# Limit Clause in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to databases and have started learning SQL.
I am trying to convert a MySQL query to work with oracle database.

I am using Oracle 11g express edition and have tried many different answers but failed miserably. I don't know why oracle has no limit clause in its SQL

This is what it looks like in MYSQL:

```
select *
from emp
order by sal desc
limit 1,1
```

I have seen many answers for how to convert limit by using rownum in oracle but couldn't find how to write offset.

I got a solution from StackOverflow:

```
select * from emp
order by sal  desc
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

but it is giving the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can anyone please suggest me some simple solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) pseudo column ?  FETCH is Oracle 12c+ i believe if i am not mistaken...

Comment: .. also what in cases on ties where the values are equal? As pagination/batching/limiting ideally requires a deterministic sort..

Comment: actually I want to fetch the 2nd highest salary from the employee's table.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to a modern Oracle version? Oracle 11 is no longer supported

Comment: My Course Instructor demands me to use Oracle 11g :(

Comment: *"I am new to databases and have started learning SQL"* As SQL is just a specification.. And `LIMIT` keyword in MySQL is a added feature which you can call a SQL dialect.. The best cross RDMS query to do this would be a corelated subquery from the old standards meaning the ANSI/iSO SQL 89/92 standards.    `SELECT table_outer.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS table_inner WHERE table_inner.sal  < table_outer.sal ORDER BY sal DESC) AS row_number FROM table AS table_outer WHERE row_number  = 2`

Comment: @Rehan: tell your instructor he should upgrade his lesson to the 21st century. Oracle 18 is available as an express edition as well. And if that isn't a  dedicated Oracle lesson, Postgres might be the better choice to begin with. And if it **is** a dedicated Oracle lesson he shouldn't be using an unsupported version.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: that might be portable but will be incredible slow.

Comment: *"that might be portable but will be incredible slow. "* indeed @a_horse_with_no_name i agree but i never said it would be the fasted method also Indexes might make it faster..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of Oracle, you need a subquery:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, row_number() over (order by c.points desc) as seqnum
      from customers c
     ) c
where seqnum = 2;
```

You will see examples that use `rownum` in the outer query:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*
      from customers c
     ) c
where rownum = 2;
```

However, that does not work, because `rownum` is incremented only when rows are placed in the result set.  Window functions are the simplest solution in older versions of Oracle (new versions support `fetch`/`offset`).

Comment: So I cannot set the offset just like in MySQL?

Comment: @Rehan: replace offset with `seqnum >= ...`

Comment: `select *
from emp
order by sal desc
limit 1,1`
this query returns the second highest salary of the employee. How should I write it in oracle?

Comment: what does c.* means?

Comment: @Rehan . . . It means to select all the columns from the table, view, or subquery represented by the table alias `c`.

Comment: Thank you, so I got your answer as well. Basically we are assigning rownumbers toe each row  after ordering it and filtering the quantity with rownum= 2.

Comment: @Rehan . . . Yes, it doesn't use the built-in `rownum`, because `rownum = 2` would never return anything.

Comment: @GordonLinoff one Last thing wanted to ask that why it gives error if I execute query like this:
 `select *, row_number () over (order by sal desc) as rank
from emp`
any logic behind it? I am trying to select all columns from emp with a new rank column...

Comment: @Rehan . . . Use `select emp.*, . . .`.  Oracle does not support `select *` with other expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Finally worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT sal, rownum AS rnum
        FROM   (SELECT sal
                FROM   emp
                ORDER BY sal desc)
        WHERE rownum <= 2)
WHERE  rnum > 1;
```

where 1 is offset

for more detail see:
[How to add offset in a "select" query in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099414/how-to-add-offset-in-a-select-query-in-oracle-11g)

Thanks to Jeffrey Kemp and Lalit Kumar B