# i added paging but .all records dispalying in same page.i need to change dynamically

Tags: extjs

```
this is my store
```

this is my view 
        all records are showing in sigle page next button click what to change  dynamically 
    thats not working.
        i added pageing but .all records dispalying in same page.i need to change dynamically

can any one help

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         fields: ['name','email'],
            pageSize : 10,
            data: [
                   {name: 'Name1',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name2',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name3',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name4',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name5',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name6',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name7',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name8',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name9',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name10',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name11',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name12',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name13',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name14',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name15',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name16',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name17',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name18',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name19',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name20',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name21',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name22',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name23',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name24',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name25',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name26',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name27',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name28',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name29',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name30',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name31',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name32',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},

                   {name: 'Name33',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name34',    email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
                   {name: 'Name35',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},



            ]

        });
```

this is my view

```
    Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.userlist',

        title: 'All Users',





        initComponent: function() {

            Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
              title: 'Column Demo',
              store:store,
              columns: [
                  {header: 'Name',  dataIndex:'name',flex:1},
                  {text: 'Email',  dataIndex:'email',flex:1},

              ],

             renderTo:'example-grid',
             width: 350,
             height: 280,
          dockedItems: [{
              xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',   // paging
              store: store,   // same store GridPanel is using
              dock: 'bottom',  
              pageSize: 10,
              displayInfo: true
          }],






              renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });


          this.callParent(arguments);
      }



    });
```

this is my view 
        all records are showing in sigle page next button click what to change  dynamically 
    thats not working.
        i added pageing but .all records dispalying in same page.i need to change dynamically

can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you data always going to be local? If yes, you can configure paging on an in-memory data set with the memory proxy. In Ext JS 4, you can use the [Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy). In Ext JS 5, this functionality has been incorporated into the Ext.data.proxy.Memory class via enablePaging:true:

```
// for Ext JS 5
mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   fields: [...],
   data: [...],
   proxy: {
      type: 'memory',
      enablePaging: true
   }
})
```

Be aware, however, that this will only work if your dataset is in-memory. If your store is going to be loaded via a server proxy, then you'll need to follow the suggestions already provided.

Comment: I am calling ajax call .it read json data.but now data is static .how to load call data from store to proxy memory

my ajax call look like this

Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'app/data/users.json', timeout: 60000, method: 'GET', scope: this, params: '', success: function(resp) { console.log(resp.responseText);

   //store.loadRawData(resp.responseText, true);
   store.loadData(resp.responseText, true);    // i am going to load instead to static data .ajax call data but not working 
},

});

Answer (score 0):

In Ext js we can't implement  paging only at client side.Please go through the post.. 
[paging in extjs 4 grid is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501140/paging-in-extjs-4-grid-is-not-working/27501505#27501505) and through the sencha docs as wells

Comment: I am calling ajax call .it read json data.but now data is static .how to load call data from store to proxy memory

my ajax call look like this

Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'app/data/users.json', timeout: 60000, method: 'GET', scope: this, params: '', success: function(resp) { console.log(resp.responseText);

   //store.loadRawData(resp.responseText, true);
   store.loadData(resp.responseText, true);    // i am going to load instead to static data .ajax call data but not working 
},

});

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong.. you want to apply the paging for static data i.e the data which is at json file?

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {"id": 1, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
        {"id": 2, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"}
       
    ]
}

Comment: paging working fine for me .but how to load json data into memory in extjs.json data come via ajax response