# OracleDB generic paging

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I realize paging on an OracleDB table when I do not know the exact setup of the table?

I am currently developing an addressbook-connector to several different remote data sources (such as MS-Exchange, GroupWise, all kinds of Directory Services, etc.) and also different SQL databases. Among those, OracleDB.

The user is able to specify the remote database, table name as well as the column names, such as *first_name*, *last_name*, *company_etc*, etc.
But he is free to leave almost any column blank, hence I cannot rely on a single column being actually set.

Therefore, the *ORDER BY* portion of the default Oracle paging query must be realized in a similar fashion as the MSSQL query ( *ORDER BY SELECT(NULL)* ).

**I do not require strict sorting reliability**

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
OFFSET ? LIMIT ?
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
LIMIT ?,?
```

MSSQL:

```
WITH select_result AS
(
  SELECT *,
  Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SELECT(NULL))
  AS RowNum FROM table_name
)
SELECT * FROM select_result
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

OracleDB:

```
???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paging with Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle)

Comment: The SQL Server solution works for Oracle as well (you can simply use `order by 1` with Oracle)

Comment: This is perfect. Write an answer and I shall mark it as freaking correct