# C# How to get all data in Oracle database

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle

I have 21 tables in Oracle 11g, and I need to display them using `JOIN` clauses. But the query is too slow and throws an `System.OutOfMemoryException`

My current code:

```
   try
        {
            //string ConString;
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString))
            {
                //string query = "SELECT PAX.CREATION_DATE,PAX.PNR,PAX.PAX_NMBR,PAX.UPDATE_LEVEL_MOD,PAX.PAX_NAME,PAX.CHANGE_OR_CANCEL_IND,PAX_SEATS.LEG_NMBR,PAX_SEATS.INSTANCE_NMBR,pax_seats.ssr_cd,pax_seats.carrier_cd,pax_seats.seat_nmbr,pax_seats.previous_status_codes FROM PAX INNER JOIN PAX_SEATS ON PAX.PNR = PAX_SEATS.PNR";
                string query1 = "SELECT PNR FROM HISTORY_LEGS";
                string query2 = "SELECT PAX.CREATION_DATE,PAX.PNR,PAX.PAX_NMBR,PAX.UPDATE_LEVEL_MOD,PAX.PAX_NAME,PAX.CHANGE_OR_CANCEL_IND,PAX_SEATS.LEG_NMBR,PAX_SEATS.INSTANCE_NMBR,pax_seats.ssr_cd,pax_seats.carrier_cd,pax_seats.seat_nmbr,pax_seats.previous_status_codes,PAX_SSRS.SSR_NMBR,PAX_TKT.TKTNMBR,PAX_TKT.ISSUING_AIRLINE, PAX_TKT.ISSUING_OFFC_NMBR, PAX_TKT.ISSUING_COUNTER_CD, PAX_TKT.ISSUING_AGNT_NMBR, PAX_TKT.TKT_IND, PAX_TKT.TKT_STATUS, PAX_TKT.TARIFICATION_IND,PAX_TKT.S_IND,PAX_TKT.ISSUANCE_DATE FROM PAX INNER JOIN PAX_SEATS ON PAX.PNR = PAX_SEATS.PNR RIGHT JOIN PAX_SSRS ON PAX.PNR = PAX_SSRS.PNR RIGHT JOIN PAX_TKT ON PAX.PNR = PAX_TKT.PNR";
                //string query4 = "SELECT * FROM PAX";
                //string query3 = "SELECT PAX.PAX_NMBR,PAX.PAX_NAME,RES_LEGS.ARNK_IND,RES_LEGS.CARRIER_CD1,RES_LEGS.CARRIER_CD2,RES_LEGS.FLT_NMBR,RES_LEGS.CLASS_CD,RES_LEGS.DAY_OF_WEEK,RES_LEGS.FLT_DATE,RES_LEGS.LEG_ORIGIN_CD,RES_LEGS.LEG_DES_CD,RES_LEGS.CURRENT_STATUS_CD,RES_LEGS.NUMBER_IN_PARTY,RES_LEGS.DP_TIME,RES_LEGS.AR_TIME,RES_LEGS.DATE_CHANGE_IND,RES_LEGS.FLT_IRREGULARITY_IND,RES_LEGS.LEG_TXT,RES_LEGS.PREVIOUS_STATUS_CODES,RES_LEGS.MESSAGE FROM RES_LEGS INNER JOIN PAX ON RES_LEGS.PNR = PAX.PNR";
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query2, con);
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                oda.Fill(ds);
                //dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
                //dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

**Questions:**

1. How to get all data?
2. How to prevent System.OutofMemory?
3. How to speed up query execution performance?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting back from the database?

Comment: Each table have about 150,000 rows. More data will be added

Comment: Why do you need to get all the data at once?

Comment: do you have better idea? i want explore all data at once. Should i use paging. Example: 10,000 rows at one 1 page

Comment: Export them to what? A file? You don't need to load all data into memory at once to do that.

Comment: okay, thank you mason

Answer (score 0):

You can look at indexes on your key fields to speed up the query a bit perhaps, but if you are getting a lot of rows back you'll be hitting some memory caps somewhere.

If you can, I would suggest implementing some paging: [Paging with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle).

This will let you bring back smaller chunks of your data making it quicker and less likely to hit any memory limits.

Comment: Hello, i tried your suggestion "Paging with Oracle" and still gives me this error: System.OutofMemory