# Is it possible to get pagable data from list of QueryByExample in JPA?

Tags: jpa, pagination, query-by-example

A table has multiple columns and ManyToOne relationshps to/from other tables.

To collect data, query needs to be done on multiple columns with multile values and it should be pageable.

QueryByExample works well for most of the values.

But the requirement is that 2 columns need to have multiple values.

e.g. -

```
Table Person {FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Age, Gender}
```

Then the query,

```
Page<Person> = personRepository.findAll(Example.of(Person with single/no value in each column), PageRequest.of(0, 10))
```

works well.

Now, the requirement is to have List for FirstName and LastName.

e.g. -

```
List<String> firstNames = Arrays.asList("AName", "BName", "CName")
List<String> lastNames = Arrays.asList("xName", "yName", "zName")
```

How to **query** Person with **Pagination**?

Comment: Your question asks about paging with QueryByExample, but you have that working. Does this work with QueryByExample at all, as I don't think Spring supports multiple example objects in its api even without paging in the mix. If it doesn't, you'd have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

- Use native Query with pagination method
- Use parameter for number of page and line >>
  [sql pagination method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/241643/22065347)